# Github.io page isn't showing, why?

Tags: github-pages

I've been working on a github.io portfolio using the front-end framework [semantic.ui](https://1.semantic-ui.com/). 
I have created a repo called leinefran.github.io, and inside of it I have another repo [web_static](https://github.com/leinefran/leinefran.github.io/tree/master/web_static) where all the files live[enter link description here](https://github.com/leinefran/leinefran.github.io). The main css file is in a CDN, and I have added the link to the top of my html file. Even though I have all things in place, I can't visualize what I have done so far when visiting the link https://leinefran.github.io/. Why is that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your work can be found at https://leinefran.github.io/web_static/. It seems https://leinefran.github.io/ is serving your README.md file.

My guess is you should move your index.html file to https://github.com/leinefran/leinefran.github.io main folder or check documentation for changing directory that is served by github.